# npm list dependencies of dependencies before install

Tags: npm, npm-install

'npm list' can only be run to show the installed packages, while I want the same command that can be run before the install (to predict whether or not the install will work).

Lets say you have a package.json with dependency A. A has dependencies B,C and D, while D has a dependency to E. Is there a command to generate the whole list with versions of what versions will be installed?
eg

```
A
--B
--C
--D
---E
```

edit:
'npm view testpackage' seems to show first dependencies before install but it doesn't go beyond lvl 1